# Multiple fo:retrieve-marker with same name

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Two page footers are having same fo:retrieve-marker:-  retrieve-class-name , retrieve-boundary & retrieve-position now if I am calling the marker-class-name with a fo:marker from xsl-region-body which footer it will be get retrieved ? And Why?

Below is the sample

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="second-page-footer" font-family="normal" font-style="normal" font-size="4">
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
        <fo:block-container position="absolute"  top="20mm">
           <xsl:call-template name="pageTwoFooter"/>
        </fo:block-container>
</fo:static-content>

<fo:static-content flow-name="rest-page-footer" font-family="normal" font-style="normal" font-size="4">
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
</fo:static-content>



<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="8pt" font-family="normal" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal">
   <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
           <xsl:call-template name="continuedNextPage"/>
   </fo:marker>
<fo:flow>
```

Or what will be the correct understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some indirection going on here that determines which `fo:static-content` is used.

The `region-name` on each `fo:region-*` on a `fo:simple-page-master` differentiates that particular region from the other regions on the page. When an `fo:simple-page-master` is used to generate a page in a page sequence, if there is an `fo:static-content` with a `flow-name` that matches the `region-name` of one of the regions of the current `fo:page-master-sequence`, then the content of that `fo:static-content` is directed into that region of the generated page. Any `fo:static-content` that does not have a corresponding `fo:region-*` does nothing for that page.

An `fo:page-sequence-master` lets you set up the conditions for selecting between different `fo:simple-page-master`. The most obvious uses for this are to select a different `fo:simple-page-master` for the first page generated from an `fo:page-sequence` than for the rest of the pages or to select different `fo:simple-page-master` for odd pages than for even pages.

In your case, you seem to be using a different `fo:simple-page-master` for the second page in a page sequence than is used for the rest of the pages.

If the `fo:simple-page-master` for the second page has `<fo:region-after region-name="second-page-footer"/>` and the `fo:simple-page-master` for the rest of the pages has `<fo:region-after master-name="rest-page-footer"/>`, then when the formatter generates pages for the page sequence, it will use the content of `<fo:static-content flow-name="second-page-footer"...` on the second page and use the content of `<fo:static-content flow-name="rest-page-footer"...` on the rest of the pages.

Please also see the XSL-FO parts of the descriptions in the 'Page Layout' and  'Headers & Footers' chapters of the 'XSL-FO/CSS Comparison' available at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-css-comparison

Comment: Thank you for this detail explanation; now I need to understand which retrieve-class-name will be called if footer is being marked with multiple fo:marker classes and all 3 classes are being implemented in fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" in different different sequence; please see below from further comments

Comment: <!--Footer def:--> <fo:static-content flow-name="second-footer"> <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="lastPage" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/> <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/> <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/> <fo:block> TEST </fo:block> </fo:static-content>

Comment: CASE A: <!--fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" started--> </fo:block-container> <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued"> <xsl:call-template name="somePageTemp"/> </fo:marker> <fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage"> <fo:block/> </fo:marker> <--Make page 1 body template--> <--Page break--> <fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine"> <fo:block> <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/> </fo:block> </fo:marker> <--Make page 2 body template-->

Comment: CASE B: <!--fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" started--> </fo:block-container> <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued"> <xsl:call-template name="somePageTemp"/> </fo:marker> <fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage"> <fo:block/> </fo:marker> <fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine"> <fo:block> <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/> </fo:block> </fo:marker> <--Make page 1 body template--> <--Page break--> <-Make page 2 body template-

Comment: what impact will be there in O/P for 2 cases? Any function is there, can use to get the fo:retrieve-marker properties, area fetched at run time after footer are being called?

Comment: Can you edit your question or make a new question so that the code can be formatted as code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851839/which-retrieve-class-name-will-be-called-if-footer-is-being-marked-with-multiple  --> as you suggested this is my new question link.

Comment: If this explanation works for you, then please consider accepting it.