# which retrieve-class-name will be called if footer is being marked with multiple fo:marker classes

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to understand which retrieve-class-name will be called if footer is being marked with multiple fo:marker classes and all 3 classes are being implemented in fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" in different different sequence;

```
<!--Footer def:--> 
<fo:static-content flow-name="second-footer">
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="lastPage" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/>
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
     <fo:block> TEST </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

CASE A:

```
<!--fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" started-->

    <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
      <xsl:call-template name="somePageTemp"/>
    </fo:marker>
    
    <fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage">
      <fo:block/>
    </fo:marker> 

**<--Make page 1 body template-->
<--Page break-->**

<fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine">
 <fo:block>
  <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/>
 </fo:block>
</fo:marker>

<--Make page 2 body template-->
```

CASE B:

```
<!--fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" started-->

<fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
  <xsl:call-template name="somePageTemp"/>
</fo:marker>

<fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage">
  <fo:block/>
</fo:marker>

<fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine">
 <fo:block>
  <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/>
 </fo:block>
</fo:marker> 

**<--Make page 1 body template-->**
**<--Page break-->**
**<-Make page 2 body template- –>**
```

Which fo:maker class will be retrieved based upon the
1.retrieve-position
2.retrieve-boundary
Or retrieval logic will be different based upon different factor?

what impact will be there in O/P for 2 cases?

Any function is there, can be use to get the fo:retrieve-marker properties, area fetched at run time after footer are being called
(if I can do that then I might be able to try sample runs and print properties, area in my O/P to understand more)?

Now if I am changing my footer definition to below:

```
<!--Footer def:--> 
<fo:static-content flow-name="second-footer">
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="lastPage" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/>
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"/>
     <fo:block> TEST </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

What will be the impact for both CASES now?
just try to understand effect of retrieve-boundary page-sequence as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sometimes do things like change the `color` or `background-color` values on FOs in different `fo:marker` to gauge which marker is used where.

The point of having markers is that there's some stuff -- such as the dictionary-style first and last terms repeated in the header -- where the formatter doesn't know what content to use until the body of the page is laid out. So, in general, you can't always predict which marker will be used on every page. In the dictionary case, if you add one new dictionary entry, it might change the headers on every page from the page containing the new entry through to the end of the document or, for a short entry, it might have no effect on the headers: you won't really know until you format the document.

Your case is a bit more predictable because you are forcing a page break and looking at the page after the break, but I'm still just making an educated guess...

In Case A, I think you would see only the content of the 'continuedLine' marker. The first area for the parent of the 'continued' and 'lastPage' markers is on the first page, so those markers aren't attached to an area starting on the second page, while the `retrieve-boundary="page"` says to only look at the current page. The 'continuedLine' marker, OTOH, would be attached to an area that does start on the current page, but it could have been attached to an area on the first page because the `retrieve-boundary="document"` says to look backwards to the beginning of the document to find the best match.

In Case B, I think that you would also only see the 'continuedLine' marker, because of that `retrieve-boundary="document"`.

Comment: I had updated   my question , for a different footer definition what will be the effect now?

Comment: @RitoSarkar: Don't move the goalposts. The question has been answered. Post a new question.

Comment: @mzjn yes sure but before this also in one of my question i was been asked that i can edit same question as well for further clarification hence I had done that, never mind will open a new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873399/which-retrieve-class-name-will-be-called-if-footer-is-being-marked-with-multiple

Comment: Some clarifications do come across as expansions, so thank you for making a new question. Half the point of SO is that someone can later search SO to find an answer to their own problem, and that becomes harder if the questions don't have a single focus.