# which retrieve-class-name will be called if footer is being marked with multiple fo:marker classes but with different retrieve-boundary value

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to understand which retrieve-class-name will be called if footer is being marked with multiple fo:marker classes and all 3 classes are being implemented in fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" in different different sequence;

```
<!--Footer def:--> 
<fo:static-content flow-name="second-footer">
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="lastPage" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/>
   <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"/>
     <fo:block> TEST </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

CASE A:

```
  <!--fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" started-->
    
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
          <xsl:call-template name="somePageTemp"/>
        </fo:marker>
        
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage">
          <fo:block/>
        </fo:marker> 
    
    **<--Make page 1 body template-->
    <--Page break-->**
    
    <fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine">
     <fo:block>
      <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/>
     </fo:block>
    </fo:marker>
    
    <--Make page 2 body template-->
```

CASE B:

```
 <!--fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" started-->
    
    <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
      <xsl:call-template name="somePageTemp"/>
    </fo:marker>
    
    <fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage">
      <fo:block/>
    </fo:marker>
    
    <fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine">
     <fo:block>
      <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/>
     </fo:block>
    </fo:marker> 
    
    **<--Make page 1 body template-->**
    **<--Page break-->**
    **<-Make page 2 body template- –>**
```

CASE C:

```
<!--fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" started-->

        <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
          <xsl:call-template name="somePageTemp"/>
        </fo:marker>

    **<--Make page 1 body template-->
    <--Page break-->**

        <fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage">
          <fo:block/>
        </fo:marker> 

    <fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine">
     <fo:block>
      <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"/>
     </fo:block>
    </fo:marker>

    <--Make page 2 body template-->
```

For second page which fo:maker class in footer will going to be retrieved for all the cases based upon the retrieve-boundary property in footer?

Updating the question:

So below is the sample xslt code that ran with different footer combination:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin-top="10mm" margin-bottom="10.5mm" margin-left="18mm" margin-right="18mm">
        <fo:region-body/>
        <fo:region-before extent="10mm" region-name="first-page-header"/>
        <fo:region-after  extent="35mm"  region-name="first-page-footer"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="second-page" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin-top="10mm" margin-bottom="10.5mm" margin-left="18mm" margin-right="18mm">
        <fo:region-body/>
        <fo:region-before extent="10mm" region-name="second-page-header"/>
        <fo:region-after  extent="35mm" region-name="second-page-footer"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="pageOneSequence">
        <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="first-page"/>
        <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="second-page"/>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="pageOneSequence">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="first-page-header">
        <fo:block>Page1 Header</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="second-page-header">
        <fo:block>Page2 Header</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="first-page-footer">
        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="lastPage" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/>
        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
        <fo:block>Page1 footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="second-page-footer">
        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="lastPage" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/>
        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
        <fo:block>Page2 footer</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued">
            <fo:block>From continued  marker class</fo:block>
        </fo:marker>
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="lastPage">
            <fo:block>From lastPage marker class</fo:block>
        </fo:marker>
        <fo:block  margin-top="9.50mm"> This is page 1 body </fo:block>
        <xsl:if test="Path/Param = 'YES'">
            <fo:block page-break-before="always"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <fo:block>
            <fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine">
                <fo:block>After page 1 From continuedLine  marker class</fo:block>
            </fo:marker>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block  margin-top="9.50mm"> This is page 2 body </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Also attaching the generated pdf image [retrieve-marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYs07.png)

So here what I am seeing irrespective of retrieve-boundary in page all the footers are getting called and been implemented; so what will be the actual implication of this retrieve-boundary values ?

Comment: Have you tried running these with FOP to see what you get? How did that compare with your current understanding?

Comment: Can you show the FOs that are the parents of the `fo:marker`? An `fo:marker` child of `fo:flow` could potentially be the retrieved marker on every page in the page sequence.

Comment: @TonyGraham yes I had tried to implement my understanding that I had till now; so I had edited the question can you please check and suggest further comment /input ?

Comment: @TonyGraham so i see you talked about retrieve-boundary="page-sequence" and retrieve-boundary="document"  will going to have the same effect when we have only one fo:page-sequence ; what about the retrieve-boundary="page" considering we had only one fo:page-sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I used Antenna House Formatter and got the same result as you (when the optional `break-before="page"` is included).

The 'From lastPage marker class' and 'From continued  marker class' are present because the `fo:marker` on the `fo:flow` apply to areas on every page of the page sequence. (Strictly speaking, it would be every page that includes a region with a `region-name` that matches the `flow-name` of the `fo:flow`.)

The 'After page 1 From continuedLine  marker class' is present because the `fo:block` parent of the `fo:marker` generated an area on the page.

---

When you have only one `fo:page-sequence`, `retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"` and `retrieve-boundary="document"` have the same effect.

---

An `fo:flow` does not generate any areas, but it does return the areas generated by its descendants. `fo:marker` are defined as attached to areas *returned* by their parent FO:

> Each fo:marker is conceptually attached to each normal area returned by the fo:marker's parent formatting object.

so conceptually every area in the body region has the `fo:marker` from the `fo:flow` attached to it, which means that those markers are available on every page. It's not important whether the `fo:marker` are attached only to the top-level areas returned by the children of the `fo:flow` or to all areas, because every non-blank page will have all or part of at least one of the top-level areas that are returned by the `fo:flow`.

When the best possible marker, e.g., the 'first-starting-on-page', isn't available, the formatter will use the hierarchy of available markers to find a marker with a matching class name, so the `fo:marker` on the `fo:flow` will be considered if there is no better match.